# Integrate iCheck plugin with knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, icheck

Can somebody help me to correctly integrate `iCheck` plugin with `knockout`? because I tried to use custom binding to initialize the plugin to my radio button but it's not updating the value of the view model.

### HTML

```
<div data-bind="foreach: InstituteContactNumber">
   <div class="controls multiple-controllers">
       <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: CNoId" />
       <input class="tb-contact-no" type="text" data-bind="value: CNo" />
       &nbsp;
       **<input type="radio" name="radio-cno" 
                     data-bind="RadioButton: { checked: IsPrimary }" />**
         <i class="fa fa-trash-o ctr-btn" style="color: red;" 
               data-bind="click: $parent.RemoveContactNo, visible: $index() > 0"></i>           
   </div>
</div>
```

### knockout binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.RadioButton = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        //initialize icheck to the element
        $(element).iCheck({
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue'
        });

        $(element).on('ifChecked', function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            // trying to change the observable value
            observable.checked = true;
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        //initially fires but it not fired when I tried to change the observable value
        //I hope that means the value has not been changed
        //anyway I have checked the model on submit, it also did not contain the values.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//trying to change the observabe value
observable.checked = true;
```

You're overwriting the observable rather than setting it; you want

```
observable.checked(true);
```

Comment: What's your ViewModel?

Comment: "InstituteContactNumber" is a child element of main viewmodel and user is allowed to add contact numbers dynamically using add button click  ** instituteVM.InstituteContactNumber.push(new ContactNo({ CNoId: 0, CNo: '', IsPrimary: false })); ** and the function is **function ContactNo(data) {
    this.CNoId = ko.observable(data.CNoId);
    this.CNo = ko.observable(data.CNo);
    this.IsPrimary = ko.observable(data.IsPrimary);
}**

Comment: you are correct sir ! my bad... `observable.checked(true);` did the trick

Comment: only difference i had to do was the change the event to `ifChanged` from `ifChecked` now it is working perfectly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider making it a two-way binding for if you change the observable value yourself in your components or handlers:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.iCheck = {
        init: (el, valueAccessor) => {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            $(el).on("ifChanged", function() {
                observable(this.checked);
            });
        },

        update: (el, valueAccessor) => {
            var val : boolean = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (val) {
                $(el).iCheck('check');
            } else {
                $(el).iCheck('uncheck');
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.iCheck = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).iCheck({
            checkboxClass: "icheckbox_minimal-blue",
            radioClass: "iradio_minimal-blue"
        });

        $(element).on('ifChanged', function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element)[0].checked);
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            $(element).iCheck('check');
        } else {
            $(element).iCheck('uncheck');
        }
    }
};
```

usage:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-bind="iCheck: StaffIsHeadOffice" />Head Office
```