# Knockout customer binding valueAccessor() is not a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, icheck

I created a customer binding for icheck plug , i want update the binding object when checkbox checked .

This is my viewModel

```
            var userViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.UserFullData = ko.observable();
            self.loadObject = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: '../UserData.do/GetUser?id=1',
                    success: function (result) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(result);
                        if (data) {

                            self.UserFullData(data);  //data from ajax
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
```

Ajax data:

```
{"User":{"ID":1,"HumanID":1,"LoginName":"cccc","LoginPass":"eeee","PermissionID":1,"DepartmentID":8,"Name":"cz","Sex":1,"SexStr":null,"EName":"cheo","NickName":"b","Company":null,"Address":null,"Email":null,"Country":0,"Province":0,"City":0,"Area":0,"PersonType":0,"Mobile":null,"PhoneNumber":"123456","MSN":null,"Fax":null,"Extension":null,"LastLoginTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Position":null},"PermissionGroup":[{"ID":1,"Title":"a","View":false,"Update":true}]}
```

HTML :

'View' is a property in Array of FullUserData.PermissionGroup

```
     <div class="box" data-bind="with:UserFullData">
 <div data-bind="foreach:PermissionGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" data-bind="iCheckBinding:View">
```

following is customer binding function :

```
            ko.bindingHandlers.iCheckBinding = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                $(element).iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-blue'
                });
                var value = valueAccessor();
                var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
                if (valueUnwrapped) {
                    $(element).iCheck('check');
                }
                else {
                    $(element).iCheck('uncheck');
                }


                $(element).on('ifChanged', function () {
                    var newValue = this.checked;
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                    //observable always not a function
                    observable(newValue);

                });
            }
        };
```

now everything others works fine to me .. just observable(newValue) is not a function stucked me , i can't update my object .

anyone knows ?

Comment: Please put all of that into a **runnable** Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button) so we can see the problem live.

Comment: Take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297542/integrate-icheck-plugin-with-knockout-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're expecting `View` to be an observable, but you're doing nothing to make it an observable. The only observable in that code is `UserFullData`, which you set up here:

```
self.UserFullData = ko.observable();
```

The code in your `success` function does nothing to make anything *inside* that observable:

```
success: function (result) {
    var data = JSON.parse(result);
    if (data) {
        self.UserFullData(data);  //data from ajax
    }
}
```

If you want `View` in that structure to be observable, you have to make it so.

Comment: Yes T.J.  , I tried to declare some observable individually (like self.View=observable(true) ) , it works . but i don't think i need make every  variable in UserFullData observable . if  the data witch i want to binding  is an Array , how to handle with it ? just like i didn't make other property in UserFullData to observable , why it can be bind by default text binding ?

Comment: @ZhouCheng: You don't have to make every property observable, but if you don't make something observable, don't treat it as though it were. The value you get from `valueAccessor()` is `View`. It's not a function, so don't try to call it.

Comment: Maybe it's only one way to resolve my issue ... i tried to do it like this :                                for (var i = 0; i < data.PermissionGroup.length; i++) {                                    self.PerGroup.push({ 'Title': data.PermissionGroup[i].Title, 'View': ko.observable(data.PermissionGroup[i].View), 'Update': ko.observable(data.PermissionGroup[i].Update) });   }, now it works . is it correct ?