# Integrate iCheck plugin with dynamic radio buttons and knockout js

Tags: dynamic, knockout.js, radio-button, icheck

I have a list of radio buttons that are loading dynamically,
I've already searched in  a couple of blogs and similar questions like [Integrate iCheck plugin with knockout js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297542/integrate-icheck-plugin-with-knockout-js)

My problem is that these examples are not adding the name of the inputs dynamically using also knockout.

Here is my code of the input

```
<input type="radio"  data-bind="name:$parentContext.$data.id, value:value,iCheckRadio: radioCheckedValue,click:activate" />
```

Any advice, please.

Comment: What is the issue you are getting? what ends up as the `name`?

Comment: I mean the attribute name of each input for grouping them because I have a lot of groups of radios buttons, The issue is that is selecting all the radios, instead of that just one per group.

Comment: What is selecting it? Can you add and additional code which does the `selecting`?

Comment: Is the `name` binding custom? Usually, you use the `attr` binding to specify a name: `attr: { name: id }`

Comment: Indeed that was the issue, thanks.